# Simple (CRC-style) domain design / modelling tool

Tags: domain-driven-design, modeling

I thought this would be easy....

For a new project about to start, I'm looking for a simple Windows-based tool for domain-driven modeling - something like "digital CRC's" (Collaboration Responsibility Cards) that would allow me to easily:

- define the entities involved
- define their properties (and metadata about those properties)
- define the links between those entities

I would love to have something that's "dynamic", e.g. if I view the `Customer` entity, I would like to be able to click on the `Orders` property and be taken to the details of the `Order` class to see what's in there. This stuff should ideally be accessible to several devs inside our company, and even to a few key players from the customer's staff - so a web-based solution would be preferred...

It doesn't need to be a full-blown UML, and it should be fairly inexpensive (<= 250$ per dev if ever possible).

Any ideas? I've looked at quite a few tools, which are either:

- too big and bulky (full UML support)
- far too expensive (can't afford ClearCase licenses......)
- too closely tied to a database / storage model already (I don't need an ERM modelling tool - yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you only need a tool for capturing entities, their properties and relationships between them, yet you're not interested in the technical details (relationship type, multiplicity etc), maybe a *mind map tool* would do the job?

Checkout http://www.mindmeister.com/, you can get free accounts, can share maps with other users, history, relationship between entities etc.

It's not meant for technical diagrams though. I use it for personal stuff, but who knows, might suit your needs.